# Strange ListView behavior in Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Edited:

I have a `ListView` linked to a custom `BaseAdapter` I implemented. I set a listener to the item click event of that `ListView`. In the `getView()` I inflate an XML and show/hide some inner layouts depending on some conditions.

The thing is that the item click event is handled only if some buttons inside the layout are hidden.  I am really confused and do not understand what happens. Particularly, the buttons that shown does not let me click on the `ListView` item are btnEventReopen, btnEventPoll, and btnEventRemove.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutEventBasic"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/content_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            layout="@layout/layout_event_final_proposal" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageEventPicture"
                android:layout_width="92dp"
                android:layout_height="92dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/img_event_default"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textEventType"
                    style="@style/TextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textEventName"
                    style="@style/TextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    tools:ignore="NestedWeights" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutEventDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textEventDescription"
                style="@style/TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:visibility="gone" />

            <include
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/layout_contacts" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEventReopen"
                    style="@style/ButtonPositive"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/img_reopen_icon"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:text="@string/reopen"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEventPoll"
                    style="@style/ButtonPositive"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/img_accept_icon"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:text="@string/poll"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnEventRemove"
                    style="@style/ButtonNegative"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:drawableRight="@drawable/img_reject_icon"
                    android:paddingRight="0dp"
                    android:text="@string/reject"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btnEventShare"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/layoutEventBasic"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/img_share"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

More code...

```
        // Set the listener for handling list item click events
        listEvents.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                eventExpand(position);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you also post the code of your `onClickListener` please?

Comment: can you post your `BaseAdapter` please?

Comment: Yep, but I don't think it may help. What do you think is happening?

Comment: Could you please read my question again? I realized it happen when showing buttons.

Comment: But we can't help you if we don't look at your `onClickListener` implementation

Comment: Let me reformulate my question, I have found the problem.

Comment: Finally I found the solution!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10998383/buttons-within-listview